# Fun with PHP RegEx (preg_replace)

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

So I have a form element which is being submitted to a controller / model in an app I have built and I need to strip away any HTML which does not conform to my requirements and convert other HTML to be a proprietary tag for the app and wondered is someone could look at my regex `preg_replace` and see what could be done to improve it.

```
$postText = $_POST['post_text'];
//Regex Functions
$p1 = '~<span class=\"atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-#\" c>|<span c class \"atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-#\">|<span c class \"atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-@\">|<span contenteditable=\\"false\\" class=\\"atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-@\\">|<span contenteditable=\\"false\\" class=\\"atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-#\\">|</span>|<span>|<span c>|<span contenteditable=\\"false\\">|&nbsp;|&nbsp|<br>~';
$r1 = '';
$start = preg_replace($p1, $r1, $postText);
$clean = str_replace('_','',$start);
$users = preg_replace("~(<var data-type=\"user\" class=\"userHighlight\" id=\"(.*?)\">)(.*?)(</var>)~", "<_link>$2|$3</_link> ", $clean);
$tags = preg_replace("~(<var data-type=\"tag\" class=\"tagHighlight\" id=\"(.*?)\">)#(.*?)(</var>)~", "<_link>tag://$3|#$3</_link> ", $users);
$last = preg_replace("~(^|\\s)#(\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)~", " <_link>tag://$2|#$2</_link> ", $tags);
$spaces = preg_replace("~(^&nbsp;|&nbsp)~", " ", $last);
$divs = preg_replace("~(?:</?div>)+~", "\r\n", $spaces);
$final = preg_replace("~(<br>)~", "\r\n", $divs);
```

I am using a contenteditable div which uses the [at.js by ichord](http://ichord.github.io/At.js/) library to allow for hash tagging and user mentions I essentially want to convert the following tags (as shown above)

**Posted content**:

```
<span contenteditable="false" class="atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-#"><var data-type="tag" class="tagHighlight" id="tag://4">#Hashtag</var><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;<span></span></span></span>is <span contenteditable="false" class="atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-#"><var data-type="tag" class="tagHighlight" id="tag://2">#AnotherHashtag</var><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;<span></span></span></span>and <span contenteditable="false" class="atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-@"><var data-type="user" class="userHighlight" id="user://82">A Username </var><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;<span></span></span></span>made it so...
```

**Hashtag**:

```
<var data-type="tag" class="tagHighlight" id="tag://2">#AnotherHashtag </var>
```

**User Mention**:

```
<var data-type="user" class="userHighlight" id="user://82">A Username </var>
```

In the main my PHP is working but every now and then I get spurious HTML which I don't need.

Lastly there are some other elements in the `preg_replace()` which deal with carriage returns which in the case of my contenteditable are being sent over as `<div></div>` or `<br>` elements and I need to preserve the carriage returns.

Hopefully I have explained it all as clearly as possible, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is your actual issue ? if i'm right you get in chrome <div> and in firefox get <br> please clarify this

Comment: My main issue is more of a general one, I need to preserve carriage returns, the ```<var>``` tags need converting to the proprietary ones and the rest of the HTML needs stripping out

Comment: please enter brief data of your $_POST['post_text'] that you get

Comment: Already there, if you look at the **Posted Content** section of the question

Comment: Can you post an example of some html to expect and the desired output from replacing tags?

Comment: Currently your script returns in `$final`: `<_link>tag://Hashtag|#Hashtag</_link> is <_link>tag://AnotherHashtag|#AnotherHashtag</_link> and <_link>user://82|A Username </_link> made it so...`
Is this an example of a correct result?

Comment: I strongly recommend you step away from using Regular Expressions to parse HTML, and use a real parser in stead. Maybe take a look at [Symfony's DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

I assume you are only interessted in the `<var>`-tags (ok, also in `<div>` and `<br>` for formatting purposes), so just remove all other tags (using of string functions without regular expressions is often the better way if speed isn't unimportant) with the [PHP function strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) (`strip_tags($postText, '<var><div><br>')`)

Replacing **all** other tags than `<var>`, `<div>` or `<br>` and `&nbsp;` entities with a space

```
$clearedText = str_replace(
    '&nbsp;', 
    ' ', 
    strip_tags($postText, '<var><div><br>')
);
```

Consolidating all spaces to one after trimming trailing and leading spaces via trim(...)

```
$clearedText = preg_replace(
    '~\s+~',
    ' ',
    trim($clearedText)
);
```

Replacing all occurences of `<div></div>` and `<br>` with a windows line break

```
$clearedText = preg_replace(
    '~<div></div>|<br\s*/?>~',
    "\r\n",
    $clearedText
);
```

Converting `<var>` tags to `<_link>` tags

```
$linkText = preg_replace(
    '~<(var)[^>]*id="((?:tag|user)://\d+)"[^>]*>((?:[^<]+|<(?!/\1>))*)</\1>~',
    '<_link>\2|\2</_link>',
    $clearedText
);
```

Fixing content of `<_link>` tags with content `tag://NUMBER|#HASH` with correct content to `tag://HASH|#HASH`

```
$linkText = preg_replace(
    '~(?<=tag://)\d+(\|#(\w+))~',
    '\2\1',
    $linkText
);
```

---

**For better understading of the last two regular expressions:**

```
<(var)[^>]*id="((?:tag|user)://\d+)"[^>]*>((?:[^<]+|<(?!/\1>))*)</\1>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/StQ5gniqnTQJR7T5)

---

```
(?<=tag://)\d+(\|#(\w+))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-xH7sCbrF3MjwwFt)

Answer (score 1):

if i'm right to understand your question then this will work for you

```
$final = preg_replace("~(<+[A-Za-z0-9\/]+>)~", "\r\n", $divs);
```

this expession remove all unwanted html tags

Comment: Sorry mate this is only part of it I need to 

1. Convert ```<div>```'s or ```<br>```'s into carriage returns
2. Convert the ```<var>``` tags as per my example above
3. Remove ay other HTML which doesn't conform to 1 & 2

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple solutions to your problem.  My first choice would be to use an html parser like this [simplehtmldom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which behaves a lot like jquery then you could do stuff like

```
$html = str_get_html('<span contenteditable="false" class="atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-#"><var data-type="tag" class="tagHighlight" id="tag://4">#Hashtag</var><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;<span></span></span></span>is <span contenteditable="false" class="atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-#"><var data-type="tag" class="tagHighlight" id="tag://2">#AnotherHashtag</var><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;<span></span></span></span>and <span contenteditable="false" class="atwho-view-flag atwho-view-flag-@"><var data-type="user" class="userHighlight" id="user://82">A Username </var><span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;<span></span></span></span>made it so...');

$tags = $html->find('var[data-type=tag]');
$final = array();
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $final[]= $tag->plaintext;
}
```

I'm trying to assume from your existing code that you're trying to extract the tags and mentions and then feed that in to something else.  Rather than trying to remove the bad parts of the input, use the parser to extract the good parts then reassemble them in to your own format.

Comment: Thanks for your response, essentially there are two html elements which I want to convert the ```<var>``` tags which are proprietary to my app and the ```<div> / <br>``` which the content editable uses in place of carriage returns (```\r\n```) the rest can be removed completely. What I am looking to sort out is everything that doesn't conform to the above strip away.

Answer (score 1):

Great to meet you earlier.

Can't you just add something like this below your $final variable?

```
$final = strip_tags($final, '<var>');
```

To strip out anything that's not a 'var' tag (or any other tag you want to keep)

Apologies if I have misunderstood

Comment: thanks for that nearly there, gave you a cheeky up vote, great to meet you mate.